# Firebase web application structure for multi-page site

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have a mobile app which uses Firebase. The apps are written for iOS and Android, but the plan is to write the administration module as a website. I've built many sites using .Net, but struggling to wrap my head around a javascript-based site integrating with Firebase. The site will need multiple pages for things such as table maintenance, user maintenance, etc., but all the examples I've seen are a single HTML file. Can anyone point me to an example of a multi-html file site, or provide some direction as to best practices and how to organize the site.

Here are some of the questions I'm not sure of;

- Does the firebase initialization code only get run once, or does it need to be run in every HTML file?
- If I declare variables in some startup file (ie a var for defaultDatabase), how can I access those in another file?
- If I want to have application-wide functions, such as Firebase signin or signout, where should they go?
- What's the best way to organize and implement common components, ie page header/footer, so that they are consistent throughout all pages?

TIA for any direction.

Comment: Uh you might want to look up some info on basic javascript development then with these kind of questions. For the app you want to make, which as i understand will do a lot of creating, updating and deleting data I would recommend looking into frameworks such as Angular or React.